# solving a power 4 inequality

Tags: inequality

Solve this inequality: $x^4 - 3x^3 - 4x^2 \leq 0$

My answer (wrong) :

$x^2 (x-4)(x+1)\leq0$

Case 1

$x^2 \geq 0$ , $x\geq4$ , $x\leq-1$ NO

Case 2

$x^2 \geq 0$, $x\leq4$ , $x \geq -1$ ... so this is $x>0$, $x<4$

Case 3

$x^2\leq 0$ , $x\geq 4$ , $x\geq -1$ NO

Case 4

$x^2\leq 0$ , $x\leq 4$ , $x\leq-1$ so this is $x\leq -1$

So i got $x\leq-1$ and $4\geq x\geq 0$

The real correct answer is $-1\leq x\leq 4 $

Comment: As mentioned by Daniel below, once you have a factor which is always positive, you can ignore it.  If a factor is negative, you can ignore it after a one-time adjustment to the inequality. Always check if zero satisfies the inequality.

Comment: I would like to know why did you take the cases of x^2 < 0 ??? I mean that's the mistake in your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of examining cases was the way I learned how to do these inequalities when I was in high school (in a now-distant century...).  That method *is* perfectly fine, but I've found it sometimes confuses students when there are multiple factors.

For an improper inequality such as this (or even when it is proper), we can look for the zeroes of the function first:

$$ x^2 \ (x + 1) \ (x - 4) \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ -1 \ , \  0 \ , \ 4 \ \ . $$

The zeroes "partition" the real numbers into four intervals, which can be examined individually:  $$ \ x \ < \ -1 \ \ , \ \ -1 \ < \ x \ < 0 \ \ , \ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ 4 \ \ , \ \ x > 4 \ \ . $$

Some textbooks suggest calculating a "test number" in each interval, but we can really be more efficient than that:  we can instead just look at the *sign* of the product of these factors.  As everyone here has noted, the first factor is always positive except at the function's zeroes, so we only need to look at the factors $ \ (x + 1) \ \ \text{and} \ \ (x - 4) \ $ .  The first of these is negative for  $ \ x \ < \ -1 \ $ and positive otherwise, the second factor is negative for $ \ x \ < \ 4 \ $ and positive otherwise.  So the signs of the three factors and of the product in each interval are

**x < -1  :** $ \ + \ \cdot \ - \ \cdot \ - \ \ = \ \ + \ \  $ ;

**-1 < x < 0  :** $ \ + \ \cdot \ + \ \cdot \ - \ \ = \ \ - \ \ $ ;

**0 < x < 4 :** $ \ + \ \cdot \ + \ \cdot \ - \ \ = \ \ - \ \ $ ;

**x > 4  :** $ \ + \ \cdot \ + \ \cdot \ + \ \ = \ \ + \ \ $  .

(Crossing successive partitions then becomes like "flipping a binary switch" when the linear factors are raised to odd integer powers, or not doing so if the power is an even integer.)

The *proper* inequality  $ \ x^4 \ - \  3x^3 \ - \ 4x^2 \ < \ 0 \ $ is thus satisfied in the intervals $ \  -1 \ < \ x \ < \  0  \ \ \text{and} \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \  4 \ $ .  Since we are working with an **improper** inequality, we must also include the "zeroes" of the function, which "binds" these intervals together and affixes endpoints.  The solution interval is thus $ \  -1 \ \le \ x \ \le \  4 \ $ .

Comment: interesting, a new way of solving this question. But what is improper inequality means?

Comment: very new and efficient way, just i don't understand the proper and improper meaning

Comment: actually i get it now, improper is >= or <=, proper is > or < only thank you

Comment: just asking, what if it is a fraction like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322795/solving-inequalities-with-fractions-on-both-sides/1322901#1322901

Comment: i also post another similar question that I can't solve by using your way http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323875/inequalities-with-fraction-problem-x

Comment: @carry On http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322795/solving-inequalities-with-fractions-on-both-sides/ , **Meshal**'s edited solution uses the technique I've described.

Comment: @carry Concerning http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323875/inequalities-with-fraction-problem-x , **lab bhattacharjee**'s solution pretty much provides the argument.  Bringing all the terms to one side of the proper inequality and factoring produces $$ \frac{(\sqrt{2} + x)(\sqrt{2} - x)}{x \ (x^2 + 2)} \ > \ 0 \ \ . $$   Since $ \ x^2 + 2 \ $ has no factors and is always positive, we have the real numbers partitioned by $ \ -\sqrt{2} \ , \ 0 \ , \ \sqrt{2} \ $ .  You again step through the four intervals, now considering _quotients_ of signed numbers. (continued)

Comment: @carry In $ \ x  \ < \ -\sqrt{2} \ $ , the ratio of signed factors is $ \ \frac{ - \ \cdot \ +}{- \ \cdot \ +} \ = \ + \ $ , so the inequality is satisfied. For the three remaining intervals, the ratio is positive again only in $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ \sqrt{2} \ $ (all factors are positive).  Since the inequality is _proper_ , we have no endpoints to add on.

Answer (score 2):

$$
x^2(x-4)(x+1) \leq 0
$$
this was correct but your analysis was slightly wrong.

for real values $x^2\geq 0$ always so we can ignore that here.

we need 
$$
(x-4)(x+1) \leq 0
$$
thus if $(x-4)\leq 0\implies x\leq 4$
$$
x+1 \geq 0\implies x\geq -1
$$
thus 
$$
-1\leq x \leq 4
$$

Comment: Good +1, a small nit is $x^2\ge0$.

Comment: @Macavity ha, you are so right. Will update accordingly.

Comment: Small point: We can only ignore $x^2$ completely because $0$ is in the interval where $(x-4)(x+1)$ is negative. Generally, we need to include the zeros of each factor regardless of the sign of the function on either side.

Comment: @danielfischer Thank you. I didn't really think about that. I have updated my own mathematics tool box now. +1 (ps keep up the good work as mod)

Comment: i see interesting, so we must take account of x^2 if it is not between the interval... Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

we have $$x^2(x-4)(x+1)\le 0$$ since $$x^2\geq 0$$ for all real $x$ we obtain the two cases $$x\geq 4$$ and $$x\le -1$$ which is senseless thus we get $$-1\le x\le 4$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^4-3x^3-4x^2\le0\iff x= x^2(x^2-3x-4)\le 0\iff x^2-3x-4\le0$.

Now the quadratic polynomial $ x^2-3x-4\le0$ has two (integer) roots $-1,4$. It's a basic result on quadratic polynomials that the have the sign of the dominant coefficient outside the interval of the roots, the opposite sign between the roots, if any:
 $$x^2-3x-4\le0\iff -1\le x\le 4.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you've begun well.
x^2(x-4)(x+1)<=0
Since x^2 is always greater than 0,
Therefore, it reduces to :
(x-4)(x+1) <=0,
Which clearly has a solution:

**-1<= x <= 4**