# solving inequalities with fractions on both sides

Tags: inequality

Solve this inequality: $\frac{x^2 -2}{2} < \frac{6x^2 -8x - 1}{x+5}$.

My solution:

Multiply $(x+5)^2$ on both sides:

$\frac{(x^2 -2)(x+5)^2}{2} = \frac{x^4 + 10x^3 + 23x^2 -20x -50}{2}$

$(6x^2 -8x - 1)(x+5) = 6x^3 + 22x^2 -41x - 5 $

$\frac{x^4 + 10x^3 + 23x^2 -20x -50}{2} < 6x^3 + 22x^2 -41x - 5$

$0.5x^4 - x^3 - 10.5x^2 + 31x - 20 < 0 $

I don't think doing this way will lead to solving the question....

Comment: There should be a cubic inequality, rather than a quartic one.

Comment: Why are you multiplying both sides by $(x+5)^2$ Just x+5 will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution ($\color{red}{Edited}$):

Given 
$$\frac{(x^2 -2)}{2} < \frac{(6x^2 -8x - 1)}{(x+5)}$$
**1. Multiply both sides by 2$(x+5)^2$ *($\color{red}{Since\;}$$\color{red}{(x+5)^2\ge 0,\;the\;inequality\;is\;preserved}$)*:**
$$(x+5)^2(x^2-2)<2(x+5)(6x^2-8x-1)$$
**2. Expand and collect like terms:**
$$x^4-2x^3-21x^2+62x-40<0$$
**3. Factor the polynomial:**
$$(x+5)(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)<0$$
**4. Draw the critical points on the real line** 
[image]

We now can write the domain as the union 
$$D=D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3 \cup D_4 \cup D_5=(-\infty,-5) \cup (-5,1) \cup (1,2) \cup (2,4) \cup (4,\infty)$$
**6. By studying the sign of each factor, answer the following: Is the left-hand side negative (less than zero)?**

> - On $D_1$: $$ (-)(-)(-)(-)=(+)<0$$ which is false.
> - On $D_2$: $$ (-)(-)(-)(+)=(-)<0$$ which is true.
> - On $D_3$: $$ (+)(-)(-)(+)=(+)<0$$ which is false.
> - On $D_4$: $$ (+)(+)(-)(+)=(-)<0$$ which is true.
> - On $D_5$: $$ (+)(+)(+)(+)=(+)<0$$ which is false.

Thus the solution is 
$$x=(-5,1)\cup (2,4)$$

as shown in the following plot

[image]

Comment: From step 1 onwards this forgets that $x+5$ may be negative. Checking a few values from the solution set (say, $x\to-\infty$) would have indicated the problem. (Kudos to the upvoters.)

Comment: sorry, but if multiplying x+5 both side, it might affect the inequality sign. Because if x+5<0 then multiplying x+5 both side means the the sign have to change. right?

Comment: and the true answer is actually -5<x<1, 2<x<4

Comment: Nice catch @Did & @carry! I edited my solution and used a general argument instead of testing with arbitrary points.

Comment: If you plot the two functions in the original inequality, you find that $ \ \frac{x^2 -2}{2} \ $ is _just barely_ greater than $ \ \frac{6x^2 -8x - 1}{x+5} \ $ over the interval $ \ 1 \ < \ x \ < \ 2 \ $ .  So it is a very narrow inequality indeed there...

Comment: i see interesting thank you !!!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$\frac{6x^2-8x-1}{x+5}-\frac{x^2-2}{2}=\frac{(4-x)(x-2)(x-1)}{2(5+x)}$$

Comment: how do you know that ^

Comment: @carry Do not expect an answer from this user. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to Meshal's approach, but you can avoid having to factor a quartic. It gives the general idea for a slightly different approach as well.

Move all terms to the same side:
$$\frac{x^2 -2}{2} < \frac{6x^2 -8x - 1}{x+5} \iff \frac{x^2 -2}{2} - \frac{6x^2 -8x - 1}{x+5} < 0$$
Now put everything on a common denominator and factor the cubic in the numerator:
$$\frac{x^3-7 x^2+14 x-8}{2(x+5)} < 0 \overset{\;\color{green}{(*)}}{\iff}  \frac{(x-1) (x-2) (x-4)}{2(x+5)} < 0$$
You can make a sign table of this fraction which leads immediately to the solution set and/or follow a scheme like Meshal's.

You can also notice that all roots (three in the numerator and one in the denominator) are simple roots (i.e. their multiplicity is 1) and thus sign changes occur in each root.

These roots are in increasing order $-5$, $1$, $2$ and $4$ and clearly the inequality is not satisfied for $x<-5$ (check with a value or reason for $x \to -\infty$); so it *is* satisfied for $x \in (-5,1) \cup (2,4)$.

---

To factor in step $\color{green}{(*)}$, you can follow general algorithms or group as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{x^3}\color{red}{-7 x^2+14 x}\color{blue}{-8} 
& = \color{blue}{(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)}\color{red}{-7x(x-2)} \\
& = (x-2)(x^2-5x+4) \\
& = (x-2)(x-1)(x-4) 
\end{align}$$