# solving inequalities with fractions on both sides and one of the factors is not a real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

I followed the instructions given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322795/solving-inequalities-with-fractions-on-both-sides) to solve $\frac{(x+1)}{(2-x)} < \frac{x}{3+x} $.

I multiplied both sides by $(2-x)^2(3+x)^2$. The end result is $(3+x)(2-x)(2x^2 + 2x + 3 ) < 0.$

However, $(2x^2 + 2x + 3 )$ has only complex roots.

If I just ignore it and solve the inequation for $(3+x)(2-x) < 0$, then I get to [the right result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B(x%2B1)%7D%7B(2-x)%7D%20%3C%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B3%2Bx%7D), which is $x < -3$ or $x > 2$. However, is there any explanation for that? Is it possible to always do that, if I want the solution to be a real number?

Answer (score 1):

That $(2x^2 + 2x + 3 )$ has only complex roots is actually helpful, it means that it is always positive.  If it could be zero or negative then would need to be more careful with the inequality.  You cannot deduce $x < y$ from $zx < zy$ or $x < 0$ from $zx < 0$ unless you know that $z$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter there are complex roots; what is important here is that the trinomial is always positive, hence you can safely divide both sides of inequality by it:
$$(3+x)(2−x)(2x^2+2x+3)<0$$
$$\frac {(3+x)(2−x)(2x^2+2x+3)}{2x^2+2x+3}<\frac 0{2x^2+2x+3}$$
$$(3+x)(2−x)< 0$$

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:$$\frac { (x+1) }{ (2-x) } <\frac { x }{ 3+x } \\ \frac { (x+1) }{ (2-x) } -\frac { x }{ 3+x } <0\\ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }+4x+3-2x+{ x }^{ 2 } }{ \left( 2-x \right) \left( 3+x \right)  } <0\\ \frac { 2{ x }^{ 2 }+2x+3 }{ \left( x-2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  } >0\\ \frac { \left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }+2x+3 \right) \left( x-2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  }{ { \left( x-2 \right)  }^{ 2 }{ \left( x+3 \right)  }^{ 2 } } >0,x\neq 2,x\neq -3\\ \\ \left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }+2x+3 \right) \left( x-2 \right) \left( x+3 \right) >0\\ \left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }+2x+3 \right) =0\Rightarrow \Delta <0\\ \left( x-2 \right) \left( x+3 \right) >0\quad \Rightarrow x\in \left( -\infty ,-3 \right) \cup \left( 2;\infty  \right) \\ \\ $$
Note that here $\left( 2{ x }^{ 2 }+2x+3 \right) =0\Rightarrow \Delta <0$ means a parabola never intersects with the x line

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that if you multiply inequality with some negative number the inequality sign will change. If you square something the result will always be positive. Thats why the instructions were to multiply with squared.

Your way is not wrong, but you have to check your solutions (plug them in starting inequality) if you do it that way, because you cannot be sure that the value with which you multiplied is positive.

Answer (score 0):

If a quadratic has only complex solutions then it never intersects the $x$ axis,so it's either always $>0$ or always $<0$ depending on the sign of the leading coefficient $a$.In this case $a>0$ so you have that $2x^2+2x+3=x^2+(x+1)^2+2>2>0$.

If you had $-x^2+2x-3$ you would have $-x^2+2x-3<0$ for every $x$ since $a=-1<0$

Here's a little illustration [image]

Answer (score 0):

Define $$f(x)=\frac { (x+1) }{ (2-x) } -\frac { x }{ 3+x }.$$
Being continuous, $f$ may change its sign in its zeroes or where $f$ is undefined.  Now $f$ has no zeroes and the latter are $x=2$ and $x=-3$.  Now plug in appropriate values to find the sign of $f$ on the intervals $(-\infty,-3)$, $(-3,2)$ and $(2,\infty)$.