# inequalities with fraction problem x

Tags: inequality

$\frac{1}{x} > \frac{2x} {x^2 +2}$ solving this inequalities:

My long solution (wrong) :

multiplying $(x^2 + 2)^2 (x)^2 \dots$ (multiplying square of each denominator, getting rid of the > or < 0)

$x (x^2 +2)^2 > 2x(x^2) ( x^2 +2)$

$x(x^4+4x^2 +4)>2x^2(x^2+2)$

$x^5+4x^3+4x>2x^4+4x^2$

$x^5+4x^3+4x-2x^4-4x^2>0$

$x ( x^4 + 4x^2 + 4 +2x^3 -4x) >0 $

$x>0$ or ^ ...

This solving method doesn't look right

Comment: Should be $[(x>0) \wedge (x^4 + 4x^2 + 4 +2x^3 -4x>0)] \vee [(x<0) \wedge (x^4 + 4x^2 + 4 +2x^3 -4x<0)]$.

Comment: $x(x^2)=x^3\neq x^2$

Comment: Why are you multiplying by the square of the denominators?

Comment: Case (i), $x\gt 0$, Case (ii) $x\lt 0$. For Case (ii), the inequality is equivalent to $x^2+2\lt 2x^2$ (we multiplied both sides by the negative number $x(x^2+2)$).

Comment: $x^2 + 2$ is already positive, no need to multiply by its square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $$\dfrac1x-\dfrac{2x}{x^2+2}>0$$

$$\iff\dfrac{x^2+2-2x^2}{x(x^2+2)}>0$$

As $x^2+2>0$ for real $x,$ multiplying both sides by $x^2(x^2+2)$
$$\iff x(2-x^2)>0\iff\{x-(-\sqrt2)\}\cdot x\cdot (x-\sqrt2)<0$$

Clearly, we need to check for $(-\infty,-\sqrt2);(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2);(\sqrt2,\infty)$

As the product of three terms is negative, we need exactly one $(0<x<\sqrt2)$ or all three to be negative $(x<-\sqrt2)$

Comment: i really like the way how you twist the question and solve it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Break this up into cases.

Case 1: $x > 0$.

Multiplying both sides by $x$, we have $1 > \dfrac{2x^2}{x^2 + 2}$ (since $x$ is positive, the sign doesn't change), and so $x^2 + 2 > 2x^2$ (since $x^2 + 2$ is positive, the sign doesn't change).

Then $2 > x^2$. Now, just find the positive $x$ for which this is true.

Case 2: $x < 0$.

Multiplying both sides by $x$, we have $1 < \dfrac{2x^2}{x^2 + 2}$ (since $x$ is negative, the sign changes), and so $x^2 + 2 < 2x^2$.

Then $2 < x^2$. Now, just find the negative $x$ for which this is true.

Edit: Also, to gain some intuition to see if whatever approach you choose works, you could plot the two functions, say by putting the following in the search bar in Chrome: "y = (2x/(x^2 + 2)) and y = 1/x". This won't give you an exact answer, but it'll let you know if you're barking up the right tree.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x^2+2>0$,

$$\frac{1}{x}>\frac{2x}{x^2+2}\iff \frac{x^2+2}{x}=x+\frac{2}{x}>2x\iff x<\frac{2}{x}$$

$$\iff \begin{cases}\begin{cases}x>0\\ x^2<2\end{cases}\\\ \ \ \text{or}\\ \begin{cases}x<0\\ x^2>2\end{cases}\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}\begin{cases}x>0\\ -\sqrt{2}<x<\sqrt{2}\end{cases}\\\ \ \ \text{or}\\ \begin{cases}x<0\\ x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{2})\cup(\sqrt{2},+\infty)\end{cases}\end{cases}$$

$$\iff \begin{cases}0<x<\sqrt{2}\\\ \ \ \text{or}\\ x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{2})\end{cases}$$

Comment: @carry You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

As both sides of the inequation have the same sign, it is equivalent to:
$$\frac{x^2+2}{x}=x + \frac2x> 2x\iff x<\frac2 x\iff\begin{cases}x^2<2&\text{if}\enspace x>0,\\x^2>2&\text{if}\enspace x<0\end{cases}$$
Thus the solutions are $\,(0< x<\sqrt 2)\,$ or $\,(x<-\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: $\,(x<-\sqrt 2)$ I agree. But the next piece is $\,(0<x<\sqrt 2)$

Comment: Oops! One of my lapsus. Thanks for pointing it. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

In response to @Bernard's answer, I offer the graph of both sides of the inequality.

[image]

I respect the member who DVs this as 'not an answer,' but, of course, not every answer here is a complete answer. A hint has value, as does a method of confirming one's algebraic solution.

The graph's intercepts, where we set the inequality to an equality, does a good job offering the two points of interest, where the curves cross. $\,(x+/-\sqrt 2)$

Again, not a full solution, but an aid to verification.

Comment: thanks for your hint, they are helping to give a more clear picture

Comment: most welcome! @Bernard's answer is correct, but I find that High School students benefit from seeing these graphs for better understanding of exactly what's going on.